# Django - Unknown field(s) (groups) specified for User

Tags: python, django

I am facing this error when I am trying to do makemigrations and migrate. I have created a custom user model and when migrating I am facing this issue. I only face this issue when I add "AUTH_MODEL_USER = account.User" to settings.py without this I am able to migrate the code.

**NOTE:**
1) Before creating the custom user I had did some experiment using wagtail, so to do the experiment I had created superuser and I don't know whether this issue is because of superuser being created before creating a custom user model.
2) I didn't add any code in admin.py and form.py yet, I wanted to check whether I'm able to migrate the code before typing any further code.

*account/model.py*

```
    from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
)

class Program(models.Model):    
    program_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    program_start_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    program_end_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def created(self):    
        self.created_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def updated(self):    
        self.updated_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):    
        return str(self.program_name)

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):    
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, is_active=True, is_admin=False, is_staff=False):    
        if not email:    
            raise ValueError("User must have an Email Address")
        user_obj = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password) # Changing the user password
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password=None):    
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True
        )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):    
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_admin=True
        )
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):    
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' # Email as Username
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):    
        return self.email
```

*settings.py*

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'account.apps.AccountConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'wagtail.contrib.forms',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
    'wagtail.embeds',
    'wagtail.sites',
    'wagtail.users',
    'wagtail.snippets',
    'wagtail.documents',
    'wagtail.images',
    'wagtail.search',
    'wagtail.admin',
    'wagtail.core',
    'modelcluster',
    'taggit',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.User'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'wagtail.core.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'Databasename',
        'USER': 'Username',
        'PASSWORD': 'Password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'

WAGTAIL_SITE_NAME = 'Myproject'
```

*account/admin.py*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Program
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

from .forms import UserAdminCreationForm, UserAdminChangeForm
from .models import User


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserAdminChangeForm
    add_form = UserAdminCreationForm

    list_display = ('email', 'admin')
    list_filter = ('admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('admin',)}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Program, ProgramList)

# Remove Group Model from admin. We're not using it.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

*account/forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from .models import User

class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class UserAdminChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'active', 'admin')

    def clean_password(self):        
        return self.initial["password"]
```

*Error*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 332, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 399, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 540, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 533, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Desktop\Version-3\empoweru\empoweru\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\urls\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from wagtail.admin.urls import password_reset as wagtailadmin_password_reset_urls
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\urls\password_reset.py", line 3, in <module>
    from wagtail.admin.views import account
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\views\account.py", line 14, in <module>
    from wagtail.users.forms import (
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wagtail\users\forms.py", line 178, in <module>
    class UserCreationForm(UserForm):
  File "C:\Users\nikes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 266, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (groups) specified for User
```

Comment: Please post your code and the error message with full traceback.

Comment: @selcuk Sorry I was facing an issue in posting the code, this is my first time using stackoverflow. I have posted the code

Comment: All good. Please post the error message with full traceback too, as I mentioned above.

Comment: @Selcuk Have posted the error.

Comment: Please add your UserCreationForm code also

Comment: Have added both admin and forms.py file

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem when trying to use a custom user model + Wagtail.

Answer (score 1):

Your custom User model is only inheriting from `AbstractBaseUser`, but Wagtail requires that a custom user model must at minimum inherit from `AbstractBaseUser` AND `PermissionsMixin`.

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
   ...
```

becomes

```py
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   ...
```

This will add the `groups` field to `User` that the error is complaining about not having.

https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/custom_user_models.html#custom-user-forms-example