# Attempting Django Migration generates Error: "Unknown field(s) (groups) specified for User"

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I encountered this problem whilst learning how to incorporate a Custom User Model to my Wagtail App. This Error happens when I try to run: `python manage.py makemigrations`. Also noteworthy is that, I haven't added any code to admin.py as well as to forms.py as I need to do see this migration work before making any further progress.
I have scoured the net for any such error and the closest that mirrors my own is this:  [Django - Unknown field(s) (groups) specified for User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416237/django-unknown-fields-groups-specified-for-user) .
However, it seems that the author as well as the respondents were stumped too.
I need to know if this is a wagtail issue or not, and if so, has Anyone got any ideas on how to solve/circumvent this perhaps?
Here's my code:

accounts/models.py

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
                                AbstractBaseUser,
                                BaseUserManager,
                                    )

# Create your models here.
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False): #add required_fields in here too
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an Email Address")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a Password")
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.active = is_active
        user.staff = is_staff
        user.admin = is_admin
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                        email,
                        password=password,
                        is_staff=True
        )
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                        email,
                        password=password,
                        is_staff=True,
                        is_admin=True
        )
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
        Custom User that will be an alternative to the Django default User
    """
    email= models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True) # db_index=True
    active= models.BooleanField(default=True) # can the user login?
    staff= models.BooleanField(default=False) #staff
    admin= models.BooleanField(default=False) # admin of our site
    timestamp= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' # this will take the place of username field

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []  # Effected during python manage.py createsuperuser

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email


    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin
```

settings/base.py

```
"""
Django settings for sch_admin project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home',
    'search',

    'wagtail.contrib.forms',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
    'wagtail.embeds',
    'wagtail.sites',
    'wagtail.users',
    'wagtail.snippets',
    'wagtail.documents',
    'wagtail.images',
    'wagtail.search',
    'wagtail.admin',
    'wagtail.core',

    'modelcluster',
    'taggit',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # custom apps
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',

]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'  # changes built-in user model to our custom one

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    'wagtail.core.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sch_admin.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sch_admin.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'sqlite': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DBWORKNAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DBWORKUSER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DBWORKPASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DBWORKHOST'),
    }
}


DATABASE_ROUTES = [
    'sch_src.router.NonMinerDevAttributeRouter'     # Router's module path
]


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
]

# ManifestStaticFilesStorage is recommended in production, to prevent outdated
# Javascript / CSS assets being served from cache (e.g. after a Wagtail upgrade).
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


# Wagtail settings

WAGTAIL_SITE_NAME = "sch_admin"

# Base URL to use when referring to full URLs within the Wagtail admin backend -
# e.g. in notification emails. Don't include '/admin' or a trailing slash
BASE_URL = 'http://example.com'

# logging functionality

import logging.config
LOGGING_CONFIG = None

logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            # exact format is not important, this is the minimum information
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs/lumberjack.log'),
            'formatter':'verbose',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
    # below is the root logger - handles any logs sent from any python module
        '': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
        },
    },
})
```

Error Encountered:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 52, in <module>
    run_command()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 46, in run_command
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:/baronprojects/pythonprojects/djangoprojects/sch_mgmt_project/sch_src\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 579, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 572, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:/baronprojects/pythonprojects/djangoprojects/sch_mgmt_project/sch_src\sch_admin\urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\urls\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from wagtail.admin.urls import password_reset as wagtailadmin_password_reset_urls
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\urls\password_reset.py", line 3, in <module>
    from wagtail.admin.views import account
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\views\account.py", line 14, in <module>
    from wagtail.users.forms import (
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\users\forms.py", line 178, in <module>
    class UserCreationForm(UserForm):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 266, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (groups) specified for User
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who may encounter this same error in Future whilst working with either Django or Wagtail specifically, I found a solution to this particular problem: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.7/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html#user-accounts .
This quote stood out for me:

```
Custom user models are supported, with some restrictions;   
Wagtail uses an extension of Django’s permissions framework,   
so your user model must at minimum inherit from AbstractBaseUser and PermissionsMixin.
```

Apparently, one is required to inherit from both `AbstractBaseUser` as well as `PermissionsMixin`, i.e. :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
                                AbstractBaseUser,
                                BaseUserManager,
                                PermissionsMixin,
                                       )

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # insert other code here
```

- Once I did this, I was able to use the commands `python manage.py makemigrations` as well as `python manage.py migrate`

For further reference:
* makemigrations:

```
manage.py@sch_src > makemigrations
Tracking file by folder pattern:  migrations
Migrations for 'accounts':
  accounts\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model User

Following files were affected 
 C:\baronprojects\pythonprojects\djangoprojects\sch_mgmt_project\sch_src  
\accounts\migrations\0001_initial.py
Process finished with exit code 0
```

- migrate:

```
manage.py@sch_src > migrate
Tracking file by folder pattern:  migrations
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, contenttypes, home, sessions, taggit, wagtailadmin, wagtailcore, wagtaildocs, wagtailembeds, wagtailforms, wagtailimages, wagtailredirects, wagtailsearch, wagtailusers
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying accounts.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0001_squashed_0016_change_page_url_path_to_text_field... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0017_change_edit_page_permission_description... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0018_pagerevision_submitted_for_moderation_index... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0019_verbose_names_cleanup... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0020_add_index_on_page_first_published_at... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0021_capitalizeverbose... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0022_add_site_name... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0023_alter_page_revision_on_delete_behaviour... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0024_collection... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0025_collection_initial_data... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0026_group_collection_permission... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0027_fix_collection_path_collation... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0024_alter_page_content_type_on_delete_behaviour... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0028_merge... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0029_unicode_slugfield_dj19... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0030_index_on_pagerevision_created_at... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0031_add_page_view_restriction_types... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0032_add_bulk_delete_page_permission... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0033_remove_golive_expiry_help_text... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0034_page_live_revision... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0035_page_last_published_at... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0036_populate_page_last_published_at... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0037_set_page_owner_editable... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0038_make_first_published_at_editable... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0039_collectionviewrestriction... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0040_page_draft_title... OK
  Applying home.0001_initial... OK
  Applying home.0002_create_homepage... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying taggit.0001_initial... OK
  Applying taggit.0002_auto_20150616_2121... OK
  Applying wagtailadmin.0001_create_admin_access_permissions... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0041_group_collection_permissions_verbose_name_plural... OK
  Applying wagtaildocs.0001_initial... OK
  Applying wagtaildocs.0002_initial_data... OK
  Applying wagtaildocs.0003_add_verbose_names... OK
  Applying wagtaildocs.0004_capitalizeverbose... OK
  Applying wagtaildocs.0005_document_collection... OK
  Applying wagtaildocs.0006_copy_document_permissions_to_collections... OK
  Applying wagtaildocs.0005_alter_uploaded_by_user_on_delete_action... OK
  Applying wagtaildocs.0007_merge... OK
  Applying wagtaildocs.0008_document_file_size... OK
  Applying wagtaildocs.0009_document_verbose_name_plural... OK
  Applying wagtaildocs.0010_document_file_hash... OK
  Applying wagtailembeds.0001_initial... OK
  Applying wagtailembeds.0002_add_verbose_names... OK
  Applying wagtailembeds.0003_capitalizeverbose... OK
  Applying wagtailembeds.0004_embed_verbose_name_plural... OK
  Applying wagtailembeds.0005_specify_thumbnail_url_max_length... OK
  Applying wagtailforms.0001_initial... OK
  Applying wagtailforms.0002_add_verbose_names... OK
  Applying wagtailforms.0003_capitalizeverbose... OK
  Applying wagtailimages.0001_squashed_0021... OK
  Applying wagtailredirects.0001_initial... OK
  Applying wagtailredirects.0002_add_verbose_names... OK
  Applying wagtailredirects.0003_make_site_field_editable... OK
  Applying wagtailredirects.0004_set_unique_on_path_and_site... OK
  Applying wagtailredirects.0005_capitalizeverbose... OK
  Applying wagtailredirects.0006_redirect_increase_max_length... OK
  Applying wagtailsearch.0001_initial... OK
  Applying wagtailsearch.0002_add_verbose_names... OK
  Applying wagtailsearch.0003_remove_editors_pick... OK
  Applying wagtailsearch.0004_querydailyhits_verbose_name_plural... OK
  Applying wagtailusers.0001_initial... OK
  Applying wagtailusers.0002_add_verbose_name_on_userprofile... OK
  Applying wagtailusers.0003_add_verbose_names... OK
  Applying wagtailusers.0004_capitalizeverbose... OK
  Applying wagtailusers.0005_make_related_name_wagtail_specific... OK
  Applying wagtailusers.0006_userprofile_prefered_language... OK
  Applying wagtailusers.0007_userprofile_current_time_zone... OK
  Applying wagtailusers.0008_userprofile_avatar... OK
  Applying wagtailusers.0009_userprofile_verbose_name_plural... OK
```

Comment: Good job tracking this down, and nice writeup! The "custom user models" section of the Wagtail docs should really have mentioned this too, so I've now added this for the next release... https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/commit/d65532dd0f0bf297523a4925fd79286b1d403a5d

Comment: Thanks alot. I Appreciate your work, At least next time guys wont fumble over this.